# plot probability

Tags: plotting, probability-or-statistics

Hi I just want to flatten a function,  I tied it with Joined->True, but it did not work, hope somebody of you can help me.

This is my code:

```
Remove["Global`*"]
m = 30; (*number of banks*)
n = 5;(*number of defaults*)
AssetV = 100;(*asset value at T*)
DebtV = 80;(*debt value at T*)
μ = 0.2;(*annual drift*)
σ = 0.3;(*annual volatility*)
T = 5;(*years*)
ρ = 0.8;
```

Since I want to use a BinomialDistribution I calculated the individual probabilities through:

```
P = (CDF[NormalDistribution[], -(Log[
        AssetV/DebtV] + (μ - 0.5*σ^2)*T)/(σ*Sqrt[
      T])])
```

In the following I generated a table where I wanted to see the probabilities where k=n1, varies from 0 to 30 since n=30, and this is given by:

```
data1 = Table[
  Probability[x >= n1, 
   x \[Distributed] BinomialDistribution[30, P]], {n1, 0, 30, 1}]
```

In order to plot the probabilities I entered:

```
Plot[Probability[x >= n1, 
  x \[Distributed] BinomialDistribution[30, P]], {n1, 0, 30}, 
 PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {"# of Defaults", "PD"}, 
 Filling -> Axis]
```

and now I just want to flatten this function. I tried it with Joined-True, which did not work out.

I want also to show the density by:

```
DiscretePlot[PDF[BinomialDistribution[30, P], n1], {n1, 0, 30}, 
 PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {"# of Defaults", "PD"}, 
 Joined -> True]
```

However, is there the possibility to implement data1=Table[...] into the two functions, would it be then possible to generate the plot by the ListLinePlot function?

thank you for your help.

Comment: is your question on how to combine plots?

Comment: @Stefan no my question is, how to flatten the plot given by Plot[Probability[...]] and if it is possible to implement data1 into Plot[Probability[...]].

Comment: @Nasser I want the results from Plot[Probability[...]] to be a combined/connected line

Comment: Perhaps `Exclusions -> None` is the option you're looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean like this? (no place to put in comment, will remove if not)

```
 data = Table[{n1, 
    Probability[x >= n1, 
     x \[Distributed] BinomialDistribution[30, P]]}, {n1, 0, 20}];
ListPlot[data, Joined -> True, Mesh -> True, PlotRange -> All, 
  Frame -> True, PlotStyle -> PointSize[.02], GridLines -> Automatic, 
  GridLinesStyle -> LightGray]
```

[image]

side-by-side

[image]

Comment: @ Nasser thank you, that was exactly what I was looking for